# tabbarcontroller d'ont appear 

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, tabbar

I' have a problem. I would like to add a `tabbarcontroller` to my based view project 
in the `appdelegate` class I added a `tabbarcontroller` and this the code
`appdeegate.h`

```
...........
UITabBarcontroller * tab;
@property (retain,nonatomic) IBOutlet UITabBarcontroller * tab;
appdelegate.m
...........
@synthesize tab;
[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked for the connection in IB?

Comment: In the nib (mainwindow.xib) i maked a connection betwen tabbarcontroller ans the window. the tabbar appear but without item text...

Comment: have you set the title for tab bar item.